# extraction of inverted green channel response for image in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to extract inverted green channel response of an image using MATLAB. I have implemented it but i don't know is it correct or not. I will be very grateful for help.
[image: green channel response]
[image: inverted green channel]

```
y = x(:, :, 2);  %green channel
z=255-y; % inverted green channel
```

Comment: 255 might be wrong for images with a higher colour depth.

Comment: Dear, I am inverting only the green channel response the green channel only have 0 to 255 intensity levels.

Comment: But this doesn´t have to be true for all images. So @Daniel R comment is right. Please add all important to your question to avoid such comments.

Comment: I have uploaded the images

Comment: @ArslanAhmad: The green channel has 0..255 for images with 8 bit per channel. This is very common, but not a constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A somewhat more versatile approach would be

```
%// Green channel
y = x(:, :, 2);  

%// Invert the green
if isinteger(y)
    z = intmax(class(y))-y;
elseif isfloat(y)        
    z = 1 - y;
elseif islogical(y)
    z = ~y;
else
    error('Strange image you''ve got there...');
end
```

NOTE: this assumes the image is in RGB colorspace, Additionally, if it's of class `float`, it assumes that the values are normalized to 1. You might need a couple more checks if there is a chance that this can be different.

In any case: document these limitations!

Comment: Nice use of `intmax`!

Comment: I found no difference between my approach and the proposed one

Comment: @ArslanAhmad: That is because you only have `uint8` images. If you would use your code with `uint16` or `uint32` images, it fails. I *did* say my code is more versatile. I *didn't* say that your implementation is wrong; it just only works in your particular context.